# Why "false | true" is 1 but not true in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I ask about it because if you try it in Java:

```
boolean a = true, b = false;
boolean c = a | b;
```

Then in `c` variable will be `true` value. But if we run similar code in JS:

```
var a = false, b = true;
var c = a | b;
```

Then in `c` variable will be `1` value.
How to explain this strange behavior?

Comment: Java is not JavaScript.

Comment: I'd guess it's something to do with you using the bit-wise operator.

Comment: `var c = a || b` and see. You need to refer [bitwise OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#.7C_(Bitwise_OR)) ,[logical OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_(.7C.7C))

Comment: Why is it strange? What are you expecting it to be and why?

Comment: Zegline their is also type conversion `boolean c = 1` gives `true` in Java whereas `var c = 1` gives `1` in JavaScript, So you are confused because of variable type and implicit type conversion in Java, Otherwise `false | true` is one in both languages as you are applying bitwise operator - both languages are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

| is a [bitwise operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators). When you write “false | true” then it is treated like 0|1.

From MDN:

> Performs the OR operation on each pair of bits. a OR b yields 1 if
>   either a or b is 1. The truth table for the OR operation is:

```
a   b   a OR b
0   0   0
0   1   1
1   0   1
1   1   1
```

Also as correctly commented by Grijesh, that in Java `boolean c = 1` gives true  whereas in Javascript `var c = 1` gives 1 due to the type conversion. The implicit type conversion happens in Java but not in Javascript.

Here is a good article to read: [All about types in Javascript – Automatic type conversion](http://united-coders.com/matthias-reuter/all-about-types-part-2/)

> The logical operators in javascript work on any type, unlike in Java.
>   **And unlike in Java, they do not return a boolean value.** Still they expect boolean values and if not given two the operands are converted
>   to boolean.

Comment: now it is correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

`||` means OR and returns `true`.

```
true || false; // true
false || true; // true
```

`|` is actually a bit-wise operator that interprets it like `0|1` and returns the number `1` because bit-wise operators can only work on numbers.

```
false | true; // 1
0 | 1;        // 1

true | false; // 1
1 | 0;        // 1
```

Comment: I think you should also add in JavaCode `c` is a boolean type (that is why it was `true`) whereas in JavaScript type is dynamic ( and value `1` doesn't converted to bool type in JS)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan That has very little to do with the reason. The main point is that `|` is a bit-wise operator.

Comment: No, every one missing this but that is first point (that is invisible easyly), - type conversion performed in Java code but not in JS

Comment: Oh, okay, because in Java it’s `true`. But that’s only because you’ve specified `c` as being a `boolean`. By default `true | false` still returns a number but is implicitly converted to a boolean by Java.

Comment: yes, that is the reason, I have added a comment regarding  this to question. You should go further and explain your answer.